# Load pictures in php file

Tags: php, jpeg, image

I want to do the following in PHP

I have pictures in a directory and i need to load the pics in a php file clean page using `"site.com/image.php?pic=xx/xx.jpg"`

Example: `http://freeminecraftaccount.org/image.php?pic=images/minecraft.jpg`

```
if (file_exists('image.html')) {
    $temfile = fopen('image.html', 'r');
    $template = fread($temfile, filesize('image.html'));
    if ($title) {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURETITLE>", $title, $template);
    } else {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURETITLE>", $notitle, $template);
    }
    if ($desc) {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTUREDESCRIPTION>", $desc, $template);
    }
    if ($pic) {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURE>", "src=\"$pic\">", $template);
    } else {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURE>", $noimage, $template);
    }
    if ($return) {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURELINK>", "<a href=\"$return\">RETURN</a>", $template);
    } else {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURELINK>", "<a href=\"/\">RETURN</a>", $template);
    }
    echo $template;
}

?>
```

If anyone could help that would be too great
Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? You need a lot more detail too. There's many ways to load an image in PHP using `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['pic'])){
       $pic_location = $_GET['pic'];
    }
    else {
       $pic_location = 'someDefault.jpg';
    }
    ?>
```

in your html body:

```
 <img src="<?php echo $pic_location; ?>"/>
```

this assumes you have the full path in the url..
otherwise prepend the path before the echo.

so if the images are stored in http://site.com/images

but the url only shows the imageName.jpg then do this

```
<img src="http://site.com/images/<?php echo $pic_location; ?>"/>
```

Comment: If isn't isset generates a notice, use a ternary operator for check it

Comment: And if isn't isset $pic_location? Man just do it  <img src="<?php echo isset($_GET['pic']) ? $_GET['pic'] : 'default.png'; ?>"/>

Comment: i need something like that but working!
http://freeminecraftaccount.org/image.php?pic=images/minecraft.jpg

Comment: show your php code for line 70 - 73 where you specify the image src="/"

Comment: To keep the XSS vulnerability low, please clean inputs!

Comment: so in your page source your image has NO src.. where in the code are you declaring $pic?